# Same code in Codepen giving different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have this pen: https://codepen.io/dteiml/full/PNMwZo with the following javascript code:

```
$('#getWeather').on('click', function() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

function success(pos){
  // get longitude and latitude from the position object passed in
  var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
  var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
  // and presto, we have the device's location!
  console.log("test");
  $('body').html('You appear to be at longitude: ' + lng + ' and latitude: ' + lat);

}

                 });
```

and html code:

```
<button id="getWeather">
Get my location
</button>
<body>
</body>
```

that I forked from somebody that works and one that I created myself http://codepen.io/dteiml/full/aNevrE with the *same exact* code and settings that doesn't work. What might be the problem?

Comment: Warning in the console: getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Had you checked the error console, it would have explained exactly what the difference is:

`https` vs `http`

> pen.js:3 getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See [redacted] for more details.

(Sorry for the redated, I couldn't post the answer exactly as given because of the link.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use https:// instead of http:// google dont accept request from http protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your codepen to https://codepen.io/dteiml/full/aNevrE and it should work.

Here is the warning:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

```
code
```